# Why is $n(n+1)$ is congruent to 0,1, or 2 modulo 5?

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to understand the following proof:

**Show that the difference of two consecutive cubes is never divisible by 5.**

For any integer $n$, we have $(n + 1)^3 − n^3= 3n(n + 1) + 1$,
and

> it is easily seen that $n(n + 1)$ is congruent to $0, 1,$ or $2$ modulo
>   $5$

so that $(n + 1)^3 − n^3$ can only be congruent to $1, 2,$ or $4$ modulo $5$.

How did the author of this proof arrive at the highlighted part? I am having trouble justifying it and determining why it is true.

Thanks!

Comment: Just check the possibilities. For example, if $n$ is congruent to $2$, then $n+1$ is congruent to $3$, so $n(n+1)$ is congruent to $6$, which in turn is congruent to $1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is just a couple of possibilities to check.

1. If $n \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$ or $n \equiv 4 \pmod{5}$, then $n(n+1) \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$.
2. If $n \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$ or $n \equiv 3 \pmod{5}$, then $n(n+1) \equiv 2 \pmod{5}$.
3. If $n \equiv 2 \pmod{5}$ , then $n(n+1) \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$.

Comment: first case is 0 in the mix, second case is twice multiplicative inverse of $n$ in the mix, third is multiplicative inverse of $n$ in the mix.

Comment: Any comment on the downvote?

Comment: I upvoted so it wasn't me.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee no problem, that's to whoever downvoted. I actually would like to know, what's wrong whenever someone downvotes, not for revenge, but it's rare to see the answer :(

Answer (score 2):

Just consider all cases:
$$
\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
n \bmod 5 : & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4
\\
n^2+n \bmod 5 : & 0 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 0
\end{array}
$$